# Remove elements from array of objects that contain the same name

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

How do I remove elements from an array of objects with the same name? In the case below, I want to remove elements 0 and 2 because the name is the same. I figured I could loop over every case but that seems wasteful.

```
array(1) { 
 [0]=> object(stdClass)#268 (3) { 
         ["term_id"]=> string(3) "486" 
         ["name"]=> string(4) "2012" 
         ["count"]=> string(2) "40"
 } 
 [1]=> object(stdClass)#271 (3) { 
         ["term_id"]=> string(3) "488" 
         ["name"]=> string(8) "One more"
         ["count"]=> string(2) "20"  
 } 
 [2]=> object(stdClass)#275 (3) { 
         ["term_id"]=> string(3) "512" 
         ["name"]=> string(8) "2012"
         ["count"]=> string(2) "50"  
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over the array, calculating how many times each name appears. Then you filter away those elements appearing more than once using [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter). This will have an average runtime complexity of `O(n)` (assuming `O(1)` for arrays), compared to the naive `O(n^2)` case.

Code:

```
$counter = array();
foreach($array as $val) {
  $n = $val->name;
  $counter[$n] = (!isset($counter[$n])) ? 1 : 2;
}
$result = array_filter(
            $array,
            function ($item) use ($counter) { return $counter[$item->name] == 1; }
          );
```

For PHP versions before 5.3 you cannot use closures, so in that case, modify your code to this:

```
$counter = array();
foreach($array as $val) {
  $n = $val->name;
  $counter[$n] = (!isset($counter[$n])) ? 1 : 2;
}

function my_filter($item) {
    global $counter;
    return $counter[$item->name] == 1;
}
$result = array_filter(
            $array,
            'my_filter'
          );
```

Note that this is only useful in reality for large arrays since there's some overhead involved. It may also be hard to read if you don't understand what's being done. For small arrays (a few hundred elements or so) I recommend you to use the naive quadratic-time loop approach.

Answer (score 2):

If it are objects of classes you can modify, you could let the `__toString()` method return the `name` property and use [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php):

> Two elements are considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2. In words: when the string representation is the same. The first element will be used.

Comment: Why doesn't array_unique allow a callback function? PHP is really inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array_filter(
  $array,
  function ($item) use ($name) { return $item->name != $name; }
);
```

Note, that this is exactly this "loop over every case" you mentioned. There is no other solution, if you want to check every item.

Comment: Huh, I'm not quite sure what this is doing to be honest, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Yet set `$array` and `$name`. You should read the official manual (there is nothing special within this single expression).

Comment: It does not do what the question asks.

Comment: Baba, no, this answer is what kylex SPECIFICALLY didn't want, and it's also wrong since there are other solutions (no, I wasn't the one downvoting).

Comment: Ok I get it now ... i have fixed the code .. i still think its not enough for someone to down vote him .. am sure he was just in a hurry and wrote the code +Emil for the clarification +1 salathe for the reply

Comment: @Baba You should consider writing your own answer instead of breaking other ones...